# How do I change the drive that I boot from but still boot to the same distro?

Tags: hard-disk, storage, nvme

I am using pop os and I just got an nvme drive.

I am not sure what I need to move there and how.

I am also not quite sure where to start as I have never done anything storage related more complicated than changing the bios boot order.

I would be very appreciative is someone would tell me what to do as I would like to speed up the boot time. I don't really mind about the speed of everything else.

Comment: You want the full install on the NVMe drive and if small can have /home or data partition(s) on existing drive. Do new install & restore from normal backup. You then still have current install, if your backup is not complete. Good test of backup as restoring backup is the only way to know it really is good.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, I'll try to see what happens if I get an iso and plug it into my computer. I think I remember the install having such options.

Comment: You do not have a good backup of /home, list of installed apps and anything else you may have added that is not part of a standard install?. No need to backup system as easy to reinstall that. Good backup should be first task to resolve.